# Django: send dictionary/list data to form

Tags: django, forms, dictionary, listbox, dropdown

**GOAL**: Send a dictionary of data to a form, to be used in a dropdown boxself.

Views.py

```
form = FormsdbForm(initial={'user': default_state})
# (to set the default value of the 'user' field)
```

Forms.py

```
class FormsdbForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ROOMLIST = (('roomID_abcdefghi','Room ABC'),
                ('roomID_jklmnopqr','Room JKL'))
    roomid = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=ROOMLIST)

    class Meta:
        model = Formsdb
        fields = ('user', 'uniqueid', 'roomid')
```

The above setup displays a form where the field 'roomid' is a dropdown box showing to entries:

- Room ABC
- Room JKL

After saving, the database is populated with the matching 'RoomID_xxxxxxxxx'
Perfect so far!

In my Views.py I have a dictionary (that I can easily convert into a list-of-lists) with the data that is now statically configured in Forms.py  (ROOMLIST).

**QUESTION:** *How can I pass this dictionary (or list) to the form so it displays a dropdown box with choices?*

This would replace the current "ROOMLIST" variable and it could easily contain 400-600 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class FormsdbView(FormView):
    # ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(FormsdbView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        ROOMLIST = (('roomID_abcdefghi','Room ABC'),
                   ('roomID_jklmnopqr','Room JKL'))
        kwargs['roomlist'] = ROOMLIST
        return kwargs
```

If you're not using `FormView`, you might also do `form = FormsdbForm(initial={'user': default_state}, roomlist=ROOMLIST)`

The form:

```
from django import forms

class FormsdbForm(forms.ModelForm):

    roomid = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.roomlist = kwargs.pop('roomlist', None)
        super(FormsdbForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['roomid'].choices = self.roomlist
```

Comment: Fantastic.. That seems to work.. Now I have to find a way to convert a *list of dictionaries*  to a Tuple-of-tuples :-(  The source data is ____ `[{"roomid_ABC":"roomname_ABC"},{"roomid_ABC","roomname_ABC"}]` __ any ideas? brain hurts..     (at least it seams that the format needs to be a tuple-of-tuples)

Comment: @user7446236 well to put a dict into a list of tuples; `[(k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems()]` so just append a list in the same way. And maybe accept my answer ;)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! apologies for the delay, was to busy trying to get this last thing fixed. ;-)